# VB.NET Everything is disabled

Tags: vb.net

For some reason, when I open my program (vb.net windows forms) everything is disabled! I don't know why. I checked if everything is disabled in properties but they are enabled. My code doesn't have any *something.enabled = true or false*. **Please somebody help me!**

Comment: The Form itself also has an `Enabled` property.